# MVC added view isn't in solution. Where is it? Possibly version control issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, version-control

This is what happened:
In my controller, I made some actionresults:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{ //...
}
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{ //...
}
```

So they're made, good stuff. But, I need a view for the first one. So, I right-click Delete, and click add view. I make the view. No problem. The view is there, it is located at: project/views/controllerfoldername/view.cshtml.

I see it in my file explorer. It's not there in the solution explorer in VS2013.

I am using team explorer and stuff, so, I'm not sure if like because I'm in source control, for some reason new files don't get added?!

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Wow yea, it's there. I thought I had hidden files being displayed. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the 'Show hidden files' at the top of the Solution Explorer. Locate the file, right click > Include in Project.